# Helo All, need input

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 3 objects, A,B,C.

B is a child of A(Lookup)
C is a child of A(lookup)

Now I want to write a trigger on object B, that whenever a B record is created all the C records linked with A object should be linked to B records also.

I am able to get the C records details in a list once B record is created, but I am not sure how to map those records. Could some one pls help me out with the trigger.

===============

```
trigger PitchElement on Pitch__c (after insert) {
    List<ID> marketingIdea = new List<ID>();
    //Marketing_Package__c MarektingIdeaList = new Marketing_Package__c();
    List<Marketing_Element__c> MarketingElements = new List<Marketing_Element__c>();    
    for(Pitch__c pitch :Trigger.new)
    {
        marketingIdea.add(pitch.Marketing_Package__c);
        System.debug('!!!!' +marketingIdea);
    }    
    Marketing_Package__c m = [select ID,Name from Marketing_Package__c where ID IN:marketingIdea];
    System.debug('@@@@@Marketing Package@@@@@@@' +m);

    MarketingElements = [select ID,Name from Marketing_Element__c where Marketing_Package__c =: m.Id];
    System.debug('Marketing elements' +MarketingElements);

}
```

Marketing_Package__c , Pitch__c,Marketing_Element__c

## A, B, C

Comment: Please post the code you tried to get the C records details, which will help us to provide solution for mapping it

Comment: Edited my post with the code...

Comment: How Pitch__c and Marketing_Element__c are related? What is the field name in Pitch__c which relates to Marketing_Element__c

Comment: Pitch__c and marketing element is child of Marketing_package, so now whenever there is pitch created i want to link all the marketing element(child of marketing package) to that particular pitch record...

Comment: To link pitch with marketing element there should be a relationship between those. We can't link them just because they are child relationship with marketing package. So create a field in marketing element which is lookup to pitch. Then in your trigger put the marketing element id you got through the query into the new field of the pitch.

Comment: what is the relationship between Pitch and Marketing element?

Comment: So is there a field in Pitch object that is lookup to Marketing Element?

Comment: There is no relationship as of now, thinking to create a junction object and map the picthes with the Marketing elelment....now sure how to do it ...

Comment: @VigneshwaranG......Marketing elemeent and pitch will have M to M relationship. ALready created a junction object. Could you please help me out with the code to insert the record in Junction object and map it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, you would create a junction object between Pitch__c and Marketing_Element__c. Let that be Junction__c which will have two lookup relationship fields Pitch__c and Marketing_Element__c objects.

The following trigger will insert Junction object records with Pitch and Marketing Element lookups.

```
trigger PitchElement on Pitch__c (after insert) {
    List<ID> marketingIdea = new List<ID>();
    //Marketing_Package__c MarektingIdeaList = new Marketing_Package__c();
    List<Marketing_Element__c> MarketingElements = new List<Marketing_Element__c>();
    Map<Id,Id> mapMarketingPitch = new Map<Id,Id>();
    List<Junction__c> lstJunction = new List<Junction__c>();

    for(Pitch__c pitch :Trigger.new)
    {
        marketingIdea.add(pitch.Marketing_Package__c);
        mapMarketingPitch.put(pitch.Marketing_Package__c,pitch.Id);
        System.debug('!!!!' +marketingIdea);
    }
    //List<Marketing_Package__c> m = [select ID,Name from Marketing_Package__c where ID IN:marketingIdea]; // This query is not required
    //System.debug('@@@@@Marketing Package@@@@@@@' +m);

    for(Marketing_Element__c me : [select ID,Name,Marketing_Package__c from Marketing_Element__c where Marketing_Package__c =: marketingIdea]) {
        lstJunction.add(new Junction__c(Pitch__c = mapMarketingPitch.get(me.Marketing_Package__c),Marketing_Element__c = me.Id);
    }
    insert lstJunction;             
}
```

Change the API names according to your actual API names.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, this is working fine. One more question i had it, I have another object which is COF__C not this is related to Pitch object, whenever pitch status changed to Order, thi COF record will be created. Now i want to relate all the Marketing elementes to this COF also ,like u have done it to Pitch.......already have a field COF on Marketing element relation object...Please suggest

Comment: If the provided solution solved your problem up vote the answer and mark it as accepted. If you have any other question, create a new question and provide a link 2 this question in that for better maintenance. Thanks

Comment: raised another question:    http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117445/hi-need-help-with-junction-object