# Hi ,need help with Junction object

Tags: trigger

Thanks for helping out me in the thread
([Helo All, need input](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117417/helo-all-need-input#)) 
where i had raised a question and helped me out to solve the problem. I have one more  question.

I have another object which is COF__C not this is related to Pitch object, whenever pitch status changed to Order, thi COF record will be created. Now i want to relate all the Marketing elementes to this COF also ,like u have done it to Pitch.......already have a field COF on Marketing element relation object...Please suggest

```
if(Trigger.isAfter)
{
    If(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        List<COF_Form__c> ClientOrderForm = new List<COF_Form__c>();
        List<COF_Form__c> clientOrderFormCount = new List<COF_Form__c>();
        List<ID> pitchRecord = new List<ID>();
        List<COF_Form__c> ClientOrderFormUpdate = new List<COF_Form__c>();
        map<Id, Pitch__c> ClientOrderFormMap = new map<Id, Pitch__c>();

        System.debug('******Trigger Entered*****');
        for(Pitch__c pitch1 :Trigger.new)
        {
            pitchRecord.add(pitch1.id);
            ClientOrderFormMap.put(pitch1.Id,pitch1);
        }

        clientOrderFormCount = [select ID  from COF_FORM__c where Pitch__c IN:pitchRecord];
        for(Pitch__c pitch :Trigger.new)
        {   
            System.debug('******Trigger Entered*****');
            if(pitch.Status__c != NULL)
            {     
                if(pitch.Status__c == 'Order' && clientOrderFormCount.size()==0)
                {
                    System.debug('******Trigger Status*****' +pitch.Status__c);
                    ClientOrderForm.add(new COF_Form__c(Pitch__c = pitch.Id,Status__c = 'Pending'));
                    System.debug('*********' +pitch.Agency1__c);
                }
            }
        }

        insert ClientOrderForm;

        ClientOrderFormUpdate = [select ID,Agency__c,Pitch__c from COF_Form__c where Pitch__c IN:pitchRecord];
        if(clientOrderFormCount.size()!=0)
        {
            for(COF_FORM__c client :ClientOrderFormUpdate)
            {
                client.Agency__c = ClientOrderFormMap.get(client.Pitch__c).Agency1__c;
            }
            update ClientOrderFormUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you create COF record on change of pitch status.

Comment: Edited my original post

Answer (score 1):

This trigger will help you out.

```
if(Trigger.isAfter)
{
    If(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        List<COF_Form__c> ClientOrderForm = new List<COF_Form__c>();
        List<COF_Form__c> clientOrderFormCount = new List<COF_Form__c>();
        List<ID> pitchRecord = new List<ID>();
        List<COF_Form__c> ClientOrderFormUpdate = new List<COF_Form__c>();
        map<Id, Pitch__c> ClientOrderFormMap = new map<Id, Pitch__c>();
        // Added            
        List<ID> marketingIdea = new List<ID>();
        Map<Id,Id> mapMarketingPitch = new Map<Id,Id>();
        // Added

        System.debug('******Trigger Entered*****');
        for(Pitch__c pitch1 :Trigger.new)
        {
            pitchRecord.add(pitch1.id);
            ClientOrderFormMap.put(pitch1.Id,pitch1);
            // Added
            marketingIdea.add(pitch1.Marketing_Package__c);
            mapMarketingPitch.put(pitch.Marketing_Package__c,pitch.Id);
            // Added
        }

        clientOrderFormCount = [select ID  from COF_FORM__c where Pitch__c IN:pitchRecord];
        for(Pitch__c pitch :Trigger.new)
        {   
            System.debug('******Trigger Entered*****');
            if(pitch.Status__c != NULL)
            {     
                if(pitch.Status__c == 'Order' && clientOrderFormCount.size()==0)
                {
                    System.debug('******Trigger Status*****' +pitch.Status__c);
                    ClientOrderForm.add(new COF_Form__c(Pitch__c = pitch.Id,Status__c = 'Pending'));
                    System.debug('*********' +pitch.Agency1__c);
                }
            }
        }

        insert ClientOrderForm;            

        // Added
        List<Marketing_Element__c> lstMarketingElement = new List<Marketing_Element__c>();
        //Query for marketing element 
        for(Marketing_Element__c me : [select ID,Name,Marketing_Package__c from Marketing_Element__c where Marketing_Package__c =: marketingIdea]) {
            if(mapMarketingPitch.get(me.Marketing_Package__c) == ClientOrderForm.Pitch__c)
                me.COF_FORM__c = ClientOrderForm.Id;
        }
        update lstMarketingElement;                 
        // Added

        ClientOrderFormUpdate = [select ID,Agency__c,Pitch__c from COF_Form__c where Pitch__c IN:pitchRecord];
        if(clientOrderFormCount.size()!=0)
        {
            for(COF_FORM__c client :ClientOrderFormUpdate)
            {
                client.Agency__c = ClientOrderFormMap.get(client.Pitch__c).Agency1__c;
            }
            update ClientOrderFormUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

One thing am not sure why you do this

```
ClientOrderFormUpdate = [select ID,Agency__c,Pitch__c from COF_Form__c where Pitch__c IN:pitchRecord];
if(clientOrderFormCount.size()!=0)
{
    for(COF_FORM__c client :ClientOrderFormUpdate)
    {
        client.Agency__c = ClientOrderFormMap.get(client.Pitch__c).Agency1__c;
    }
    update ClientOrderFormUpdate;
}
```

This can be done while insertion itself like this

```
ClientOrderForm.add(new COF_Form__c(Pitch__c = pitch.Id,Status__c = 'Pending',Agency__c = pitch.Agency1__c));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting erro :Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<COF_Form__c> at line 64 column 44